# Product AddToCart Product list page magento 1.9.1

Tags: magento-1.9, product, javascript, addtocart

I am using `JavaScript function` to `add product to cart`, below is my JavaScript code :

```
<script>
        function myFunction() {
        jQuery.ajax({url: '<?php echo $this->helper("checkout/cart")->getAddUrl($_product) ?>', 
        success: function(data) {
        console.log('Data Sent');
        }
        })  
        }
        </script>
```

Ans the button code is:

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="myFunction()"><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></button>
```

But when I click `addtocart`  the `different product` is getting added to cart, please can anybody let me know what is the issue  in the above code ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you added java-script code in bottom of file so it will always add last item from listing page.

so you need to put the JS code inside the foureach loop or you need to dynamically call URL of add to cart so update code below and try again

```
<script>
        function myFunction(addtocarturl) {
        jQuery.ajax({url: addtocarturl, 
        success: function(data) {
        console.log('Data Sent');
        }
        })  
        }
    </script>
```

and button code also

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="myFunction('<?php echo $this->helper("checkout/cart")->getAddUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></button>
```

Hope this will help you!